# Integrate Pooled Lifestyle with PerWebRequest Lifestyle in Windsor

Tags: .net, castle-windsor, pool, perwebrequest

I have ASP.NET MVC application that uses Entity Framework as ORM.
Now I'm using **PerWebRequest** lifestyle for EF **ObjectContext**.

While profiling application performance under high load, I found a bottleneck in ObjectContext creation.

I want to change **ObjectContext**'s lifestyle to **Pooled**, but there is an issue.

In legacy part of my application there is **Service Locator** anti-pattern. So the ObjectContext could be Resolved many times per web request, and not explicitly released after usage.

With **PerWebRequest** it's not an issue, because **ObjectContext** instance instantiated once and released guaranteed on **EndRequest** event.

With default **Pooled** lifestyle different **ObjectContext** instance would be returned for each **Resolve** method call. But I want to re use single instance in web request scope.
Also I want the instance to release (return to pool) automatically at the end of request (with **PerWebRequestLifestyleModule**).

It seems to me, that I should implement custom **LifestyleManager** or custom **IPool** for Windsor.
But I don't know how to combine **Pooled** and **PerWebRequest** lifestyles, because of lack of experience in Windsor.

Can you give me any ideas?
Thanks.

**UPD: About ObjectContext's state and reasons to reuse**

There is performance reason. Creation of ObjectContext is quite expensive. I'm searching for ways to avoid it. 
I have two approaches to deal with ObjectContext's stateful nature and to reuse it:

- use stateless context (with ChangeTracking turned off) for queries. For commands use another instance.
- reset context's state on returning to pool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't reuse an `ObjectContext` across requests. You will leak shared state between requests (and potentially between users). The `ObjectContext` class is not designed to be reused.

In your question I did not find a reason not to use `PerWebRequest`, so just use that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. See my update to understand the reason.

Comment: Notice that I recommend reusing the context **per request**. This is absolutely the right thing to do. Creating one context per request is next to immeasurable. If you think otherwise I'd be interested to see a measurement of yours.; A stateless context might work, I don't know enough about EF to tell. Not sure if resetting the context's state is possible. **Notice that you are introducing an element of nondeterminism here.** Usually, requests are 100% isolated, now they are not. It is like threading bugs: Nondeterministic, undebuggable. If it was my decision as the lead I'd forbid to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you could change the lifestyle to be tied to the current thread, ensuring that each worker thread in the web app gets an instance

Comment: No, the ObjectContext class should not be reused. Also, a single ASP.NET request can execute on multiple threads (non-concurrently, but still on multiple threads).

Comment: Right! I'm not an entity framework kind of guy - from the question I deduced that the ObjectContext could in fact be reused because of his own suggestion of using the pooled lifecycle